# Java Interface Declaration

Tags: java, netbeans

Hello I would like to know to start with this assignment I do not need a complete help but this is the first step and there is a lot more to code, my question is how to declare this inside the mothods which are shown below I mean if you could give an example about this that would be great, to start of working on it, how to count the numbers without me knowing the values or when I test them it takes the value that is tested  (I use netbeans if that helps)

```
  public interface StatisticalOutcomes {

  public int count();  

  public double sum();

  public double mean();

}
```

• **count**: The count method returns an integer value which is the number of elements in the set.

• **sum**: The sum method returns a double value which is the sum of the elements in
the set.

• **mean**: The mean method returns a double value which is the mean (a.k.a. the average) of the elements in the set. The mean is defined to be the sum divided by the
count.

Thank you.

Comment: Inteface declared methods are public by default. You should not be explicit declaring methods as public. Just use:  int count();  instead    public int count();

Answer (score 0):

As interfaces only **declare** methods and don't **implement** them (unless you use the **default** modifier...), you need to create a class that **implements** the interface and then overrides the methods.

```
public class ClassName implements StatisticalOutcomes{

    @Override
    public int count(){
        // Add code here.
    }

    @Override
    public double sum(){
        // Add code here.
    }

    @Override
    public double mean(){
        // Add code here.
    }

}
```

You will then be able to create an instance of the class and call the methods.